# How to rename testcase in nightwatch custom report

Tags: nightwatch.js

nightwatch report returns the testcase name.
I'm having hundreds & hundreds testcases and for easier mananament I choose to name them with code numbers instead of naming them.

Now I would like to add a custom description on the report for each testcases!

Is there a good way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

No tips but at least I will share how I did it.

I have added into the nightwatch.conf.js a global variabe type Map which will contains all my descriptions.

```
[...]
    test_settings: {
        default: {
            globals: {
                [...]
                testcaseDescription: new Map()
            },
[...]
```

Then for each testsuites I'm creating description used also for debug log

```
const DESCRIPTION = new Map();
DESCRIPTION.set('CASEXXX', "acceptance criteria for the casexxx");
```

and then push them on the global variable using a custom command

```
browser.addDescription(DESCRIPTION)
```

the custom command is quite simple :

```
exports.command = function(description) {
    let self = this;

    self.execute(
        function() {},
        function() {
            description.forEach(function(value, key) {
                self.globals.testcaseDescription.set(key, value);
            });
        }
    );
    return this;
};
```

and finaly in my reporter.js i've injected the global var description into the results using a methode addDescriptionIntoResults (which seek casename and add description)

```
testcase.description = options.globals.testcaseDescription.get(casename) || 'No Description';
```

and send it to handlebars which generate a detail report with a description for each testcases \o/